# SVN + Active Directory

Tags: svn, active-directory

How do I setup SVN (On a linux box - Centos 5.2) to authenticate using Active Directory?

Also:

- Any tips or tricks?
- What should I watch out for?
- How fine grain can I set the access? This group have access to these projects, etc?

And how does this work if I use something like tortoissvn to access my repository?

**What I have learned so far:**

you need the following modules installed for apache

- mod_ldap
- mod_authnz_ldap
- mod_dav
- mod_dav_svn
- mod_authz_svn?

Answer (score 1):

This is a very common topic.

Try [this](https://web.archive.org/web/20120625110705/http://www.sublimesvn.com/blog/2009/02/configuring-subversion-with-active-directory-authentication/), it should work.

Comment: Welcome to Serverfault.  While this link does appear to contain an answer to the original question there is a tendency over time for links to go out of date, disappear, etc.  A brief description of the answer with the link included as support/further detail will likely prove more useful over time.